# django: static url not rendering correctly

Tags: django, django-forms

One one of my pages, the static url is not rendering correctly. For instance:

```
<link href="//static/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It's a contact form and here's the view:

```
def contact(request):

    Success = False
    email = ""
    title = ""
    text = ""

    if request.method == "POST":    
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if contact_form.is_valid():
            Success = True
            email = contact_form.cleaned_data['email']
            title = contact_form.cleaned_data['title']
            text = contact_form.cleaned_data['text']

    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm()

    ctx = {'contact_form':contact_form, 'email':email, 'title':title, 'text':text, 'success':success}

    return render_to_response('website/contact.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% if success %}
    <p>{{ email }}</p>
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>

{% else %}

<form action"." method="POST">

{{ contact_form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
{% endif %}
```

All other pages are loading corrctly, and the only difference is this form. Does anyone know what's going on?

Edit:

The template code that renders the url is:

```
<link href="/{{ STATIC_URL }}static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And the relevant settings.py code:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")

CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8')).replace('\\', '/')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, '/static/'),
)
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not rendering correctly?  Also, I admit I'm not clear on how the static link you've referenced connects to the code you've posted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean that when the html renders on course.html the static assets have the links "//static/static/" rather than "/static/" and it only happens on this page.

Comment: Okay.  Could you include a code block with the specific piece of code that's supposed to render that url, in context?

Comment: Thanks, I've added that now. For some reason it seems to be using that as an absolute path for this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to remove the duplicate 'static' ie:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Edit:**
You're not passing in a request context on the view that you think was working.  When you neglect to pass in the request context STATIC_URL is an empty string so your link  will resolve correctly (ie /static/css/boostrap.css), however when you add a request context STATIC_URL will then be replaced with '/static/' rendering the incorrect url.  **In short, to fix this: 1) use the code above to refer to bootstrap.css, 2) include the request context in all of your views.**

See the [request context docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) for more info.

Comment: I've just tried that and it gives the url correctly, but then that changes the rendered link on another page to <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> so that is now incorrect too. Both pages extend the base.html template which is used to render this information. How could it be different?

Comment: Yep, that's the one! Thank you.